# Getting error when using google cloud translate in ruby on rails 5.2.4

Tags: rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, google-cloud-translate

I am trying to execute some code in the console of my local environment, with rails 5.2.4

I have the gem

```
gem 'google-cloud-translate'
```

and I want to translate a string locally, I do:

```
      parent = @client.class.location_path ENV['CLOUD_PROJECT_ID'], 'us-central1'
      response = @client.translate_text ["madrid"], "en", parent
      response.translations.first.translated_text
```

but I get this error; (using the Heroku console for my production env I do not get any errors with the same code)

```
 +[__NSCFConstantString initialize] may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called. We cannot safely call it or ignore it in the fork() child process. Crashing instead. Set a breakpoint on objc_initializeAfterForkError to debug.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Google recommended [Ruby client library](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries/v2/ruby) to perform the translation for your requirement.

Here is the code that I used to perform the translation:

```
require "google/cloud/translate/v2"
translate = Google::Cloud::Translate::V2.new(
 project_id: "< PROJECT ID >",
 credentials: "< Change to your key.json file path >"
)
translation = translate.translate "Hello world!", to: "la"
puts (translation.text);
```

**Output:**

Salve Mundus!